How to implement coinscrash.com model of deposit & withdraw flow for my crypto poker casino?
In coinscrash.com for each user they generate separate bech32 address for deposit & displays the deposited amount as balance in top of the navigation bar.
Similarly for withdraw they just ask for the amount to be withdrawn & receiver address for withdrawal.
Currently for our setup we're generating bech32 address with publicKey & privateKey using node JS. But for sending transaction to another bech32 wallet it's more complicated to calculate transaction fee & sochain.io costs too much.
How to implement this model of deposit & withdraw model for my crypto poker casino?

Could you be more specific what the problem is with sending to a new "bech32 wallet"? Do you mean that you move the funds around before the withdrawal and thus double the transaction cost, having issues predicting the weight of the transaction, or is it something else?
